# python - datetime output time only

Tags: python, datetime

The function below takes in HH:MM:SS but returns the date.  I just want to enter the time and get out the time.

desired:

**enter** 23:23:23 > **returns** 23:23:23

currently:

**enter** 23:23:23 > **returns** 1900-01-01 23:23:23

question:

How do i get it to return only 23:23:23 time.

```
import datetime

def ObtainTime():
    while True: #Infinite loop        
        userInDate = raw_input("Type Time HH:MM:SS ")
        try:
            d = datetime.datetime.strptime(userInDate, "%H:%M:%S")
            break #this will stop the loop
        except ValueError:
            print "Invalid Input. Please try again.\n"
    return d

print ObtainTime()
```

---

Completed Code:

```
import datetime

def ObtainTime():
    while True: #Infinite loop        
        userInDate = raw_input("Type Time HH:MM:SS ")
        try:
            d = datetime.datetime.strptime(userInDate, "%H:%M:%S")
            d = d.time()
            break #this will stop the loop
        except ValueError:
            print "Invalid Input. Please try again.\n"
    return d

print ObtainTime()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `datetime.time()` to get the time.

Example -

```
>>> d = datetime.datetime.strptime("23:23:23","%H:%M:%S")
>>> d.time()
datetime.time(23, 23, 23)
```